# Forcing temporary page numbers on a style that has removed them

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, templates, journal-publishing

This is a common problem I encounter in practice: I am writing up a document such as a paper, book chapter, etc. that enforces an external stylesheet, let's call it `template.sty`. For whatever reason, `template.sty` has removed all page numbers.

At the same time, I have a strict page limit to follow. This is hard to do without page  numbers.

**My question:** Is there a way to *temporarily* force the printing of page numbers, *without* modifying `template.sty`? The idea is that I will use this while writing, and remove it at the very end before submission.

Yes, it is part of the question that `template.sty` is a black-box that you do not know anything about and cannot touch. So, the solution may not work 100% of the time, but a workaround that works (or should work) in "most" cases is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shipout hook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,lipsum}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put(0.5\paperwidth,-0.95\paperheight){\textcolor{red}{\Huge\thepage}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]